# Select a single rule (based on attribute weights) from multiple rules matched in Drools

Tags: drools

I want to be able to select 1 off the multiple rules which match the input. Logic to pickup the best match should be based on weights provided for each attribute.

eg:

```
Attrib1_Weight = 1
Attrib2_Weight = 4
Attrib3_Weight = 1

Rule1 = Attrib1, Attrib3
Rule2 = Attrib2
```

So if a condition meets both Rule1 and Rule2 -- Rule2 will be selected as Attrib2 is having weight = 4. For Rule1 total weight is 2.

I am using decision table excel.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a new constraint to each of the rules representing the weight. Then you would need to insert the weight as a fact into the engine.